# How to judge whether a polynomial have a factor of multiplicity $d$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

Let $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. To judge whether $f(x)$ has a square factor, we only need to consider the resultant $Res(f,f')$.

My question is, if we want to judge whether $f(x)$ has a $d$-multi factor, what can we do? Of course we can consider the resultant $Res(f^{(d-2)},f^{(d-1)})$ or something similar, but I think it's too coarse. We can also use the theory of multi-resultant, but it's not explicit enough.

If we ask the same question to a polynomial of multi variables, are they same?

Comment: How about $gcd(f,f',...,f^{(d-1)})$?

Comment: Of course it's right, but useless for me since it's not easy to compute. Actually what I want is something similar to the resultant but the absolute value (working over $\mathbb Q$) is less that $Res(f, f')$. Or you have some other suggestions? Thank you all the same.

Comment: It should be easy to compute. Just apply the Euclidean algorithm, working in pairs. $\gcd(\gcd(\gcd(f,f'),f''),f''')$ etc

Comment: It's complex to explain the reason why I need such a result, and your suggestion cannot be used to deal with it.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: computing the gcd of a family by iteration is not very efficient. Using Euclidean algorithm directly on the family is faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's rehomogenize to a binary form $F(x_1,x_2)=x_2^n f
\left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right)$. Then (assuming $a_n\neq0 $) the question is about detecting a factorization $F=L^d G$ where $L$ is linear. Consider all multiindices $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ of length $|\alpha|=d-1$ and introduce two sets of $d$ indeterminates $s=(s_{\alpha})_{\alpha}$ and
$t=(t_{\alpha})_{\alpha}$ indexed by these multiindices. The equations you are looking for can be obtained as the coefficients of the polynomial
$$
P(s,t)={\rm Res}\left(\sum_{\alpha}s_{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha}F,\sum_{\alpha}t_{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha}F\right)
$$
which is bihomogeneous of degree $(n-d+1)$ in $s$ and in $t$.
I think the degree $2(n-d+1)$ set theoretic equations obtained in this way are about as good as one can do for $d$ small but certainly not optimal for large $d$. In that case it might be better to use equations (for the ideal) found by Weyman in a series of three articles:

1. J. Weyman, "The equations of strata for binary forms." Journal of Algebra 122, no. 1 (1989): 244-249.
2. J. Weyman, "Gordan ideals in the theory of binary forms." Journal of Algebra 161, no. 2 (1993): 370-391.
3. J. Weyman, "On the Hilbert functions of multiplicity ideals." Journal of Algebra 161, no. 2 (1993): 358-369.

For $d$ high enough, ideal generators are quadratic and correspond to (easy to calculate) transvectants of $F$ with itself.

For more general coincident root loci see my article with Chipalkatti mentioned in my answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55162/how-can-i-write-down-polynomial-relations-that-define-when-a-polynomial-is-a-squ) and references therein.

---

Edit: the article I mentioned namely, ["On Hilbert covariants"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4761) also treats the multivariate case. Theorem 6.1 therein gives set-theoretic equations for a homogeneous polynomial $F(x_1,\ldots,x_r)$ to be of the form $G^d$. The idea is to use the binary form case and intersect your hypersurface with a variable line. With classical invariant theory it is easy to see how this translates at the level of explicit equations and this device is called the Clebsch transfer principle.

---

Edit 2: A [new article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02912) came out today with a characterization of triple roots using a "resultant of resultants". I don't yet know how this intriguing construction relates to the one I explained above.

Comment: I don't think we need to suppose the $L$ in your answer to be linear.

Comment: Could you elaborate. I took $L$ to be a linear factor simply because this is the same a root for your original nonhomogeneous polynomial. I have no idea why you have an issue with that.

Comment: now I see. You look for `multi-factors' instead of multiple roots. Then follow the link I mentioned because these are more complicated coincident root loci for partitions $\lambda=(m^d, 1^{n-md})$. My paper with Chipalkatti is about the $n=md$ case.

Comment: Actually for simple variable polynomial case they are same, but I want a result for several variables polynomial case. Of course, you can consider $f\in\mathcal O[T_0,\ldots,T_n]=\mathcal O_K[T_0,\ldots,T_{n-1}][T_n]$, but I don't know whether it's proper for my application.

Comment: just edited my answer for the multivariable case.

Comment: A further question: with all the notation same as in your above answer, we consider the case of large $n$ and small $d$. Could you control the dependence of the invariant polynomials on the degree $n$? It is important for some arithmetic problem. Thank you.